# what's wrong in this code of privilege?

Tags: php, mysqli

how to check privilege in "check"php code or page  ??

I using explode and in_array

after the user log in  and in "check" page the code must check privilege of user if he has "dataDisplay" privilege or not ..but the code in "check" page doesn't do that

what's my wrong in "check" page code

this is my Database:

```
+--------------------+-------------------------------+
| username           |   user_privilege              |
|--------------------|-------------------------------|
| amal               |7gz,agt_courses,newbill        | 
|                    |                               |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                    |                               |
| ahmed              |dataDisplay,previllige,newUsers|
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

first page "login" php:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include '../connection/connect.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


if($username && $password ){
    $finduser = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM LOGIN WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password ."'") or die("error");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($finduser) !=0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($finduser)){
            $uname = $row['username'];
            $pass= $row['password '];
            $arr=explode(",",$row['user_privilege']);
        }
    }
        {
        $_SESSION['sessionname'] =$uname;
        $_SESSION['sessionpass'] =$password ;
        $_SESSION['sessionpre'] =explode(",",$row['user_previllige']);
        header ("location:../agtSite/agt2.php");
    }
} 
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

second page "check" php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['sessionpre']='';

$haspermission =in_array("dataDisplay",$_SESSION['sessionpre']);


if( $haspermission )
{
    header("location: agt2.php");
    }

else{header("location: ../display/display.php");}

?>
```

Comment: sql injection, indentation?

Comment: I'm beginning in php how to fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add **else** block, a problem you could avoid if you indent your code properly.
Make sure you create the session only if you find a user

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($finduser) !=0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($finduser)){
        $_SESSION['sessionname'] =$row['username'];
        $_SESSION['sessionpass'] = $row['password '];
        $_SESSION['sessionpre'] = explode(",",$row['user_previllige']);
        header ("location: ../check.php");
    }
}
else{
//could not find user
}
```

Also as the others pointed out in the comments you to [prevent SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: I add "else" but still in issue

Comment: what is `agt2.php` is that `check.php`

Comment: the error message disappear but I want "check" page code to check privilege it doesn't do that what is the wrong in it

Comment: the check page return user to log in page

Comment: @user2982666 Which part of your code does this redirect, from what I can see only ahmed would be able to access display.php

Answer (score 0):

1. The `else` that others are pointing out is a problem.
2. So is the apparent typo in `user_previllige`.
3. In your `else` block, you refer to `$uname` and `$row['user_previllige']`, but these things only have meaning in the `if` block; they are undefined if you are in the `else` block.
4. Are you sure you are connected to the database?  I see `$link`, but you don't include the code you used to initiate the connection in the code above.
5. As others have pointed out, this is **extremely vulnerable to SQL injection**.
6. Also, **don't store passwords in plain text**!  Salt and hash them.  Assume that they will be stolen one day, and design your application so it wouldn't matter, because the salted and hashed value would be useless.